# jQuery hide and show trumping CSS media queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this button that appears when the window is smaller then 500px. This button shows a div.

I also have a resize function that makes the div dissapear if the window gets larger then 500px.

The only problem is, I don't want `#nav_open` to ever be shown if the width is greater then 500px but my jquery is overwriting my @media requests.

Can anyone show me what I may be doing wrong and have the CSS trump the jquery in some facet?

### [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/q7w88ebd/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav_close">OPEN</div>
<div id="nav_open">CLOSE</div>
<div id="mobile-nav-container">
  <div class="mobile-menu">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/resellers.html">FOR RESELLERS</a></li>
      <li><a href="/merchants.html">MERCHANTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="/equipment.html">EQUIPMENT</a></li>
      <li><a href="/about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a id="contact_button" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav_close, #nav_open, #mobile-nav-container { display:none; }
@media (max-width:500px) { #nav_close { display:block;} }
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).resize(function(e) {
    resize();
  });

  function resize() {
    if ($(window).width() > 500 && $('#mobile-nav-container').is(':visible')) {
      $('#mobile-nav-container').hide();
      $("#nav_open").hide();
      $("#nav_close").show();
    }
  }

  $('#nav_open, #nav_close').click(function() {
    $('#mobile-nav-container').toggle();
    $("#nav_open").toggle();
    $("#nav_close").toggle();
  });

});
```

Comment: `display:none !important; `

Answer (score 0):

Jquery's `toggle()`, `show()`, `hide()` methods apply the styles inline. Per CSS rules of [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), inline styles will override even your media queries. Although this should be generally avoided, you can add the `!important` keyword in your media queries so that it overrides the inline styles.

**CSS:**

```
@media (max-width:500px) { 
    #nav_close { 
        display: block !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do .hide() it is roughly equivalent to doing

```
.css( "display", "none" )
```

This will apply inline class to your element and inline classes have precedence over css classes :) 
Now, if you still want your css selectors to take precedence over jQuery you can use **!important** in your css classes which may help you achieving your use case.
But you may want to consider your design first.

Hope this be of some help.

Happy Learning :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `toggleClass('hide')` (or `addClass('hide')` and `removeClass('hide')`) instead of just `show()` or `hide()` will work for you as long as the bootstrap css file is loading before (above) your custom css file. Your custom css will override bootstrap's `hide` class.